# How add button 'Done' in my keyboard E-mail with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

[ExemplePic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo1Yz.png)

How add button 'Done' in my keyboard E-mail with React Native ?
Because i have only managed to keyboard number with `returnKeyType='done'`.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question. returnKeyType='done' is how you do it. Is that not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyboardType` prop.

Example: -

```
<TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardType